# How to add one more stylesheet in application.html.erb in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'authenticate', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I like to add one more style sheet "authenticate.css" along with "application.css" but I am getting error.

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError in <controller>#<action>

Asset filtered out and will not be served: add 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( authenticate.css )' to 'config/initializers/assets.rb' and restart your server
```

If I am not wrong, this wasn't the case in rails 3, I don't like to add a line of code about "authenticate.css" in "config/initializers/assets.rb". Is this the only way to add a style sheet in view in Rails 4 or am I doing something wrong ?

I don't want it to be part of application.css by calling within it or by  `* require_tree .`. I just want to call it in the view where it's required but not in all the views.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just put the authenticate.css in your assests folder?

Comment: @JTG, "authenticate.css" file is in app/assets/stylesheets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't like to add a line of code about "authenticate.css" in "config/initializers/assets.rb". Is this the only way to add a style sheet in view in Rails 4 or am I doing something wrong ?

If you look at [`docs`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), it says

> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array in config/initializers/assets.rb

so this line ***basically tell rails to precompile individual assets.***

> If I am not wrong, this wasn't the case in rails 3

If you look at this [`pull request`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/84) ***you'll see that sanity checks from the sprockets_better_errors gem have been merged into Rails 4.1. The intent is to reveal asset pipeline errors that you would see in production when you run the app in development mode***

Comment: as per you and as the docs say, In Rails4 the only way to add one more style sheet is by declaring it in "config/initializers/assets.rb", right ?

Comment: @Syed You have to include that line only if you want to make a separate manifest file, like in your case as you don't want to require it in application.css. What this line will do is make two manifest files for your css, one with application.css and other one with authenticate.css

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  *= require_tree is added in your application.css file, it will automatically add all the css which are inside your css folder and will need not to add them manually.

Comment: @Nikitha Shingh, I don't want it to be part of application.css and I just want to call it in the view where it's required but not in all the views.

Comment: Aren't you adding the new css in application layout ?

Comment: @Nikitha Shingh, No I am not adding there and also I have commented this line  * require_tree .